# Proper IF EXISTS structure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm having an issue with a stored procedure where it's updating more than the specific row needing updating.

The table contains SiloNumber, GreenBeanPartNumber and CloseGate columns. A silo can store any type of green bean and this table keeps track last CloseGate setting for each type of green bean to use the next time that green bean is placed in the silo.

Over time a silo will have multiple entries, one for each type of green bean:

SiloNumber | GreenBeanPartNumber | CloseGate

```
 30     |      1120           |   1.5
 30     |      1234           |   .5
 30     |      3213           |   2.0
 30     |      3453           |   1.1
 30     |      6522           |   1.8
```

Currently, when the stored procedure updates the CloseGate value for a specific SiloNumber & GreenBeanPartNumber, it changes all of the CloseGate values for the Silo to the same number.

SiloNumber | GreenBeanPartNumber | CloseGate

```
 30     |      1120           |   1.5
 30     |      1234           |   1.5
 30     |      3213           |   1.5
 30     |      3453           |   1.5
 30     |      6522           |   1.5
```

Here is the stored procedure used to do the update:

```
ALTER PROC [Controls].[Spclosesettings] @SiloNumber VARCHAR (50),
                                        @GBPartNo   VARCHAR (50),
                                        @value      INT,
                                        @SlowFill   VARCHAR(50) output,
                                        @CloseGate  VARCHAR(50) output
AS
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT closegate
                 FROM   controls.SiloDischargeSettings
                 WHERE  SiloNumber = @SiloNumber
                        AND GreenBeanPartNumber = @GBPartNo)
        UPDATE controls.SiloDischargeSettings
        SET    closegate = @value
        WHERE  GreenBeanPartNumber = @GBPartNo
  END
```

I've done some searching and other then the BEGIN and END being outside the `IF EXISTS` statement, this looks like it should be working.

Comment: Is that the real SP?  You don't seem to be using @SlowFill or @CloseGate and you'd also what to add `SiloNumber = @SiloNumber` to it.

Comment: I don't see how the current code would give you the incorrect results you are seeing, but a different incorrect result, updating `closeGate` for all silos for a given `GreenBeanPartNumber`

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, Yes, it is the real SP. The '@SlowFill' and '@CloseGate' I believe are leftovers from past functionality, I'm not the original developer, so I'm not 100% sure. Could be cleaned up...

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, I would agree if the `UPDATE` didn't have the `IF EXISTS`.

Comment: @DennisCCI, the `IF EXISTS` controls whether the `UPDATE` runs, but will not the change the behavior of the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, Hmmm, that's something I never thought of. I'll have to do some testing. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER Proc  [Controls].[spCloseSettings]

 @SiloNumber VarChar (50)
,@GBPartNo Varchar (50)
,@value int 
,@SlowFill varchar(50) output
,@CloseGate  varchar(50) output 
AS
BEGIN

    update t                            
      set t.closegate = @value
    FROM controls.SiloDischargeSettings t
    where t.GreenBeanPartNumber = @GBPartNo
     AND EXISTS (select 1 
                 from controls.SiloDischargeSettings 
                 where SiloNumber          = @SiloNumber 
                   and GreenBeanPartNumber = @GBPartNo
                   and t.GreenBeanPartNumber = GreenBeanPartNumber )

     IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
       SELECT @SlowFill  = @SiloNumber  --<-- only guessing here 
             ,@CloseGate = @value
End
```